# Compile error while using Joda-Time library

Tags: jar, jodatime, java

I am using eclipse with **Joda-Time 2.3** and **jdk 1.7.0_25**

I add the jar library to my eclipse java project like this:
I paste the joda-2.3.jar to the libs folder.
Then I add the JAR file to the build path:

1.Right click your project

2.Select properties

3.Go to java build path

4.Go to libraries tab

5.Add jars button

6.Browse the joda time jar file in the libs folder

7.Click ok

I write a simple class which  imports the org.joda.time.DateTime
and i get the following error:

everytime i compile i get:

```
Usage: java org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoCompiler <options> 
where possible options include:
-src <directory> Specify where to read source files
-dst <directory> Specify where to write generated files
-verbose Output verbosely (default false)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code? It seems that it is running some jar as an application

Comment: My goal is to use joda library in an android application.
But, initially,in order to test a more simple case, i am trying to insert this library to a java application.
Thus, i write a very simple java application:
import org.joda.time.DateTime;


public class Joda {
 
 public static void main() {
  DateTime d = new DateTime();
 }


}


Also, i tried to insert the library in an android application.
I just do in my code:
...
DateTime d = new DateTime();
and i get the following error:
E/AndroidRuntime(5900): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.joda.time.DateTime

Comment: I do right click on libs -> joda-2.3.jar and then add to build path and the application runs fine!

Comment: @zoevas Rather than make a comment with solution, please post an answer and accept it so as to close this question. Answering your own question is not only okay, [it is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved! I do right click on libs -> joda-2.3.jar and then add to build path and the application runs fine!